# How to handle exceptions during logging?

Tags: c#, logging, exception, language-agnostic

I thought of adding a simple logging mechanism within my application, in order to log the details of the errors that occur during operation of the application.

```
private TextWriter m_TextWriter;
private List<string> m_LogEntries;   // buffered log messages

// ...

public void Write(string message)
{
    m_LogEntries.Add(message);

    if (m_LogEntries.Count >= m_LogEntriesLimit)
    {
        Flush();
    }
}

private void Flush()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var message in m_LogEntries)
        {
            m_TextWriter.WriteLine(message);
        }
        m_TextWriter.Flush();
    }
    catch
    {
        // How to deal with exceptions?
    }
    finally
    {
        m_LogEntries.Clear();
    }
}
```

The log data are written on a text file, so some exceptions might occur during each write operation. What is the proper way to handle exceptions that occur during calls to methods of the logger? Should I catch and ignore them?

In other words, the logger is often used to log the details of the exceptions that occur during the execution of an application. But how to handle the exceptions that may occur during the writing of a log messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use a logging framework like [Log4Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial).

Also, there is a very small chance of running into exceptions in using the `TextWriter` class. You just have to make sure that:

1. Your paths and permissions are correct when opening the stream/`TextWriter` in the first place.
2. Your `TextWriter` object is not `Disposed` prematurely in addition to catching `ObjectDisposedException` explicitly
3. Specifically catching `IOException` during the write

You may need to have a `try-catch` just to be 100% sure that nothing bad happens (e.g. when external processes interfere with your logging filepaths).  If it fails, consider adding a retry with a back-off mechanism after a number of maximum tries.

Anyhow, you may just do as @AnimalStyle said, if ever that very unlikely event that that happens.

Comment: @MickyDuncan That is an opinion. The answer for OP's question is in the phrase: "Anyhow, you may just do as AnimalStyle said."

Comment: @MickyDuncan Of course it throws an exception, but that happens when you are not coding right. It's not like it's some chaotic event you have no control over. Ensure that permissions and paths are correct and TextWriter works just fine.

Comment: The question is "How to handle exceptions during logging?" Both the suggestion of Log4Net and doing what AnimalStyle is saying are both answers, are they not? @MickyDuncan

Comment: OK then, let me make it more specific per your objections @MickyDuncan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72100/discussion-between-ian-chu-te-and-micky-duncan).

Comment: Well, I think I could use a retry mechanism. Then, if an exception will occur again, the application may show the error to the user. Probably later I will use a better solution, like Log4Net.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing those types of errors to the windows event log.

Comment: Though a fine suggestion, even writing to the event log can throw **ArgumentException; InvalidOperationException; Win32Exception** which would need to be caught.  Consider revising your answer to show how to handle exceptions as per _"How to handle exceptions during logging?"_

Comment: This simply is a mitigation step in the event an exception is raised in the authors proposed logging technique. It would allow for some kind of message and information to be obtained. There is never a bullet proof solution, all solutions will have some chance of failure no matter what. Introducing a back up is the only way to increase the chance of success.